# Is it possible to upload the git bundle to Google Drive to keep development in sync?

Tags: git, git-bundle

I have some game project git folders. *There are many binary files and audio files.* The git repo is very large, so I want to use onedrive and google drive to sync my repo instead of GitHub.

My plan :

### When I finish the development:

`git add`, `git commit`
not use `git push` . Use `git bundle create ../foo.bundle --all`,
Then upload.  `rclone sync ../foo.bundle remote:foo` .

### When I switch to another computer:

Download bundle first, `rclone sync remote:foo ./foo.bundle` 
then  `git remote add origin ../foo.bundle` (if 1st time), 
`git pull`, etc..

ps.
I don't plan to upload. git directly because there are so many files in it. Uploading bundles may be more efficient.

I tested my plan.
The disadvantage is that I have to upload **FULL** bundle file again every time.

Maybe I can try incremental bundle in my plan?

Comment: Do you also need to do `git remote add origin` every time? That sounds strange — as if you have a new repository every time.

Comment: no. remote add only 1st time.

Comment: Then incremental bundles should work. What is you problem with incremental bundles?

Comment: incremental bundles is great, but i donot know how to use it. The audio file in the project folder does not need to be modified, but the text file is often modified.I'm imagining a way to put audio files and binary files into binary. bundle, and then put text files into code.bundle
In this way, I just need to update the code. bundle, and then I can synchronize my development process.

Comment: Do not think about files, think about commits. Git is about commits and branches; files belong to commits. Try an incremental bundle `git bundle create ../foo.bundle last_commit..HEAD` where `last_commit` is a commit you pushed to the previous bundle; remember it somehow — write to a file or mark using a branch.